# How to write single line of text to Excel

Tags: r, excel

I would like to write a single line of text to an Excel file using the R package openxslx. I have tried converting the text to a dataframe but end up with two lines - a header plus the text enclosed in quotes.

Is there a way of just writing text to a cell, preferably without the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
addWorksheet(wb,"new")
writeData(wb,"new","Hello this is text")
saveWorkbook(wb,output,overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

If you have your text in a variable, just change the code to `writeData(wb,"new",your_variable)`

Comment: Many thanks, this worked fine. I was under the misapprehension that only dataframes could be written.